# How can I visualize relative area with superimposed squares (using Python)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, jupyter-lab

I'd like to generate a data visualization of country areas as squares-within-squares / boxes-within-boxes. I'd like to render it in Jupyter and export it to, say, a PNG.

Is there an off-the-shelf way to do this? Perhaps Seaborn?

Comment: if you want png then maybe use [PIL/pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to create and work direclty bitmap `Image`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I generate the visualization?

Comment: Your description is rather vagues. Does a [treemap](https://python-graph-gallery.com/201-control-the-color-of-treemap/) go into the desired direction?

Comment: Sorry. Not exactly. I want the squares to be *nested*. A bit like in this area chart: https://interworks.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/default/files/TECTAreaChart1.jpg